# Show TCP keepalive status in Windows?

Tags: windows, netstat, keepalive

Using `netstat -to` on a Linux system shows the status of tcp keepalive for a socket like this:

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       Timer
tcp6       0      0 192.168.210.114:3389    192.168.10.57:52914     ESTABLISHED keepalive (1224,85/0/0)
```

However the Windows version of `netstat` doesn't have the `Timer` column. The argument `-o` shows the processID instead. Is there an easy way to check this in Windows (in PowerShell) ?

Answer (score 3):

No, you'd need a third party software like Wireshark to view this.
What you can view with `Resource Monitor` (resmon) is if a connection is on keepalive (the connection is greyed out) but you wont see the actual timer.

For this go to `Network` and expand on `TCP Connections`